# Unity3D - error after migrate from Unity 2017.4.X to Unity 2019.2.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I just migrate my old project from **Unity 2017.4.30f** to **2019.2.2**

However, I got below errors :

> Assets\Plugins\Easy Save 3\Scripts\Types\Unity Types\Component Types\ES3Type_EventSystem.cs(3,19): error CS0234: **The type or namespace name 'EventSystems' does not exist** in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Plugins\UDP\UdpSupport\SampleScene\Scripts\GameManager.cs(2,19): error CS0234: **The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist** in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Plugins\UnityPurchasing\script\IAPButton.cs(9,30): error CS0246: **The type or namespace name 'Button' could not be found** (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Plugins\UnityPurchasing\script\IAPButton.cs(46,16): error CS0246: **The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found** (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Plugins\UDP\UdpSupport\SampleScene\Scripts\GameManager.cs(15,13): error CS0246: **The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found** (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried to remove those component from `package manager` and reinstall it but still not solve the issue.

Any Idea ?

Thank You

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Hi, How i can check it ?

Comment: Hi, it's .NET 2.0

Comment: it does not solve, still same.....